# How to synchronise accounts between different geth installations

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

I have a problem. If I build two geth nodes A and B, these two nodes are already in communication and synchronization. I created accountA on node A, and I can unlock accountA on node A with the password. So can I unlock accountA in the console of node B?

I want to know if account information will be synchronized between geth nodes?

Hope you can give me some help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Account information is the local filesystem on a JSON file.

You can move this file between different geth installations if you want to import/export account between different installations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I still don't quite understand that if I deploy a smart contract on geth node A, the address of the smart contract is generated. Whether node B can call this contract by using its address?

Comment: This is correct. It is not related to accounts or private keys. Blockchain state is synchronised across all get nodes in the network. All nodes will execute all transactions in all blocks with they fetch over peer-to-peer network to arrive to the same local state. However your personal credentials are not transferred over blockchain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I benefited a lot !